# req.user is not being set to res.locals on app.use in express passport node js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ejs, express-session

I'm new to nodejs, I'm trying to develop a website with two users, a normal user, and a freelancer. When the user logs in `res.locals.currentUser` is set as the `req.user` by using the middleware `app.use` (I'm using the same middle-ware for both types of user).

```
app.use(session({
secret: "Rusty is the best and cutest dog in the world",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
cookie: { maxAge: 180 * 60 *1000 }
}));
```

My `app.use` code is

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
console.log("inside app use");
res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
res.locals.session = req.session;
console.log(req.user);
next();
});
```

When the user logsin req.user shows the right user but when the freelancer logsin req.user here inside app.use is undefined.

My passport configuration for the user is

```
passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

My passport configuration for the admin is

```
passport.use('freelancer', new LocalStrategy(Freelancer.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Freelancer.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Freelancer.deserializeUser());
```

The user login which works fine is

```
app.post("/user-login", passport.authenticate("user", {

failureRedirect: "/user-login"
}) ,function(req, res){
console.log("success");
if(req.session.oldUrl){
    var oldUrl = req.session.oldUrl;
    req.session.oldUrl = null;
    res.redirect(oldUrl);

}else{
    console.log("inside else");
    res.redirect("/my-user-profile/"+req.user._id);
}
});
```

The problem is with the other type of user the Freelancer.
My freelancer login route is

```
app.post("/freelancer-login", passport.authenticate("freelancer", {
failureRedirect: "/freelancer-login"
}) ,function(req, res){
res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
res.locals.session = req.session;
console.log("currentUser ------>");
console.log(res.locals.currentUser);
res.redirect("f-profile/"+req.user._id);
});
```

on my console.log(res.locals.currentUser); Im getting the correct information of the user and also the req.user shows the correct information inside this route but when Im trying to access currentUser in other ejs views , currentUser is undefined just for the freelancer 
The current user inside app.use also shows undefined (just for the freelancer).

I've been stuck at this for a long time and any kind of help would be a lifesaver

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: can you show the req object for both the cases ?

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda  it was too large to include here. I've uploaded it to a drive you can view it here.    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p9XWiDpf-54Eyn6pCdhm5gR88zXH2GwS

Comment: In req the req.user not coming in case of freelancer.

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda But isn't this code supposed to add req.user `app.use(function(req, res, next){
console.log("inside app use");
res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
res.locals.session = req.session;
console.log(req.user);
next();
});
`    Is there any solution to why its not adding?

Answer (score 3):

Raj, it might be a problem or ordering your code.

The

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
});
```

Must be on top of your code. Try that!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this for myself:

I had to change deserialize method to:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async function (id, done) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id).exec();
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});
```

Including `.exec()` fixed it.

In the axios call, I had to include:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Then in my `app.js`:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```